# Dell Laptop Crashes After Sleep and Doesn't Charge Until Dead

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, crash, sleep

I have been having a weird bug with my Dell XPS for some time. It is using the original charger, and is only about a year old so shouldn't have much wear. The problem also persists no matter which charging port I use. I am running windows 10 (although I have an Ubuntu Dual boot on the system, I just don't use it often. I use my computer primarily while connected to the charger. My problem is, when my computer goes to sleep (not immediately on closing the lid but some time after, when I wake it back up the computer crashes. Sometimes I can get about 30 seconds of use before it happens, but it always crashes.

It then reboots, I lose everything I was working on before, and facial signin doesn't work. So I signin with a pin, but again, after 1-30 seconds it crashes a second time, and only then boots up and lets me use the computer.

However, a majority of the time after that second boot, the computer stops charging, no matter the battery percentage. I then am unable to charge until the computer dies, I drain the battery, unplug and replug, and then it will work well until I decide to put it to sleep again.

I have another issue which I think is related. My background battery usage is very high, like one day the background battery usage of google chrome (10 tabs probably) was 70% battery, and the lid was closed the whole time. My sleep settings are both 4 minutes / 10 minutes, so I don't think its connected to those timeouts, but I don't want to lower them, as then I will have to deal with the initial problem more often. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be a driver or hardware issue. Have you reached out to Dell? I've had issues with my Dell computer in the past and they ended up replacing some of the hardware.

Comment: The battery could be dying, even if the computer is new.

Comment: Agree with @harrymc, it could be a dead or faulty battery.

Comment: Your machine should have a battery reset function in the Dell Battery app. Try resetting the battery.  Make sure all drivers and BIOS have been updated. Use the Dell Driver Update app. Is the computer still under warranty?

Comment: I would probably try disabling (for troubleshooting): the camera; any fingerprint reader; the trackpad (have a usb mouse handy). In my experience (with admittedly older laptops) Synaptics biometric drivers can cause this

Comment: I vaguely recall someone citing a "race condition" on sleep.

Comment: I haven't spoken to dell but I don't think its a hardware issue, the battery health is shown as perfect and everything works normally until specific software crashes. I've disabled the camera, and am attempting to reset the battery in the Dell Power Manager App, but do not see the option. How do I reset it @John?

Comment: I cannot find a ready Dell article (typical). Charge up, unplug, run down to laptop shutdown.  Plug in, allow to fully charge, then finally restart and check battery condition. Still talk to Dell.